# Swift Selector on UIScreen brightness returning UIDevice when invoked

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

I have the following snippet

```
    let classByName = objc_lookUpClass("UIScreen")


    let mainScreen = (classByName as? NSObjectProtocol)?.perform(Selector("mainScreen"))?.takeRetainedValue()
    print(mainScreen) // Optional(<UIScreen: ....
    print(mainScreen?.perform(Selector("brightness")).takeUnretainedValue()) // Optional(<UIDevice:...
```

As you can see the second method returns a reference to the current UIDevice instead of the CGFloat corresponding to a screen brightness...

Any idea on what's going on here?

Comment: Why not simply using `UIScreen.main.brightness`?

Comment: Because that's not fun :). Jk, I am trying to learn more on how selectors work.

Answer (score 0):

You run into a corner case due to using dispatch methods that are not recommended in Swift.

Please note that everything you read below is related to the Objective-C message passing (aka method calling). When interoperating with Objective-C classes, the Swift compiler generates (more or less) the same caller code as the Objective-C compiler, so anything that applies to Objc, also applies to Swift code calling ObjC.

---

First of all, `performSelector` should not be used on methods that return float, since behind the scenes `performSelector` calls `objc_msgSend`, however for methods that return a float, the internal result of `objc_msgSend` is read from the wrong location.

A little bit of background of `objc_msgSend` - this function is at the core of the Objective-C dynamic dispatch, basically any method call on an Objective-C object results in `objc_msgSend` being called. I won't get into too many details here, there are many online materials about `objc_msgSend`, just want to summarize that the function is a very versatile one, and can be casted to match any method signature.

So, let's take the `brightness` example. What actually happens behind the scenes when using `performSelector` (the Objective-C method named in Swift `perform(_:)`)? This is roughly how `performSelector` is implemented:

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)selector) {
  return objc_msgSend(self, selector);
}
```

Basically the method simply forwards the value resulted by calling `objc_msgSend`.

Now the things get interesting. Because floats and ints use different return locations, the compiler will need to generate different reading location depending on its knowledge about the type of data returned by `objc_msgSend`.

And if there's a misunderstanding between what the compiler thinks `objcSend` will return, and what actually the function returns, then bad things might happen. But in your case there's a "fortunate" coincidence due to which your program doesn't crashes.

Basically your `perform(Selector("brightness")` call results in a `objc_msgSend(mainScreen, Selector("brightness"))` call that assumes that `objc_msgSend` will return an object. But in turn the called code - the `brightness` getter - returns a float.

So why isn't the app crashing when the Swift code tries to print the result (actually it should crash on `takeUnretainedValue`)?

It's because floats and ints (and object pointers are in the same category as int) have different return locations. And the `performSelector` reads from the return location for ints, as it expects an object pointer. Fortunately, at that point in time, the last method called is likely a method that returns an `UIDevice` instance. I assume that internally `UIScreen.brightness` asks the device object for this information.

Something like this happens:

```objectivec
1. Swift code calls mainScreen?.perform(Selector("brightness")
2. This results in Objective-C call [mainScreen performSelector:selector]
3. objc_msgSend(mainScreen, selector) is called
3. The implementation of UIScreen.brightness is executed
4. UIScreen.brightness calls UIDevice.current (or some other factory method)
5. UIDevice.current stores the `UIDevice` instance in the int return location
6. UIScreen.brightness calls `device.someMemberThatReturnsTheBrightness`
7. device.someMemberThatReturnsTheBrightness stores the brightness into 
the float return location
8. UIScreen.brightness exits, its results is already at the proper location
9. performSelector exits
10. The Swift code expecting an object pointer due to the signature of
performSelector reads the value from the int location, which holds the 
value stored at step #5
```

Basically, it's all about calling conventions, and about how your "innocent" code gets translated into assembly instructions. This is why the fully dynamic dispatch is not recommended, because the compiler doesn't have all the details to construct a reliable set of assembly instructions.